# How to apply different styles to specific button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, conditional-operator

I have an image on which I'm applying different filter overlays. I want to apply specific styling based on the button pressed by the user. How can I achieve this?

Right now I'm using ternary condition but its just applying for one styling

```
       <Image
          source={{
            uri: source,
          }}
          style={styles.filterImage}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
        <View
          style={
           filter1 ? styles.filterOverlay1 : styles.defaultFilterOverlay
          }
```

I have made multiple states for different filter overlays

```
  const [filter1, setFilter1] = useState(false);
  const [filter2, setFilter2] = useState(false);
  const [filter3, setFilter3] = useState(false);
  const [filter4, setFilter4] = useState(false);
  const [filter5, setFilter5] = useState(false);
  const [filter6, setFilter6] = useState(false);
  const [filter7, setFilter7] = useState(false);
```

When the user is pressing on a button its setting the state to **true**

```
           <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.filterTags}
              onPress={() => setFilter1(true)}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Filter 1
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.filterTags}
              onPress={() => setFilter2(true)}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Filter 2
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.filterTags}
              onPress={() => setFilter3(true)}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Filter 3
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a ternary condition like this

```
style={
       filter1 ? styles.filterOverlay1 : filter2 ? styles.filterOverlay2 :  filter3 ? styles.filterOverlay3 : filter4 ? styles.filterOverlay4 :styles.defaultFilterOverlay
      }
```

or you can use filters like this

```
const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState(styles.defaultFilterOverlay);
```

on TouchableOpacity press

```
<TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.filterTags}
          onPress={() => setSelectedFilter(styles.filterOverlay1)}
        >
```

and set the selected filter

```
 style={ selectedFilter  }
```

Comment: Your answer is partially correct as it is valid for only one filter overlay. When I'm pressing on filter2 button for styling of filterOverlay2, styles were not applied because filter1 state is true and it is also setting filter2 button state to true. However I have found a workaround by setting every other filter state false when any specific filter is true.

Comment: <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.filterTags}
              onPress={() => {
                setFilter2(true);
                setFilter1(false);
                setFilter3(false);
                setFilter4(false);
                setFilter5(false);
                setFilter6(false);
                setFilter7(false);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                Filter 2
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>``

Comment: Can you tell me any better approach? - @Jagjeet Singh

Comment: @WahasAliMughal I added another way to use filters in my answer. maybe it works for you